# unable to open many websites

Tags: server, 20.04

I have installed Ubuntu Server 20.04.1 LTS version in Oracle VM Virtual Machine, and in that, I have run the following commands `sudo ufw allow 80` & `sudo ufw allow delete 80`, does this command make any effect on actual Ubuntu 20.04 OS?

because after that I have removed Ubuntu Server 20.04.1 LTS from Oracle VM Virtual Machine and deleted related files, and after that many websites not opening properly, but the same website is opening perfectly on different Internet Connections.

can anyone please guide me or help what to do now?

Kind Regards,
Dhaval

Comment: probably looks like your internet connection is blocking the URL.Check with your internet provider

Comment: but before doing the above things, every Website was working perfectly fine, so I just want to be sure that this is not happening due to above thing

Comment: What type of error you are facing in opening the website and on the same system you are able to visit the same site with different internet providers. Am I right?

Comment: Sorry for getting back to you late, but I found that those websites wasn't loading was due to ISP, and this problem is solved 3 days back. I am extremely Sorry for reaching out back late.

Comment: Its okay mate happy to know your issue resolved.